# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'

Tags: wcf, authentication, windows-authentication

1) On Machine A - I have created an WCF service and hosted it IIS 5.1, on MachineA. which is running under this URL `http://mydomain/SetupPOCService/Service1.svc`

2) On Machine B - I created an Asp.net Web Applciation. In this application I tried to consume the previously created WCF service which is now hosted on another m/c i.e. MachineA.
When I run this web application from Visual Studio environment, it access that MachineA's WCF service and get the data.

---Fine till here---

3) On Machine B - Now I hosted My Web Application in IIS5.1
This web application is working fine here but could not able to acces that MachineA's WCF service and giving this kind of error.

**The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.**

StackTrace
**[MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.]**

I tried so many things but it dint helped.
Please give your inputs...

**Below is Web.Config for client**

```
 <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
  <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
   realm="" />
  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
 </security>
```

**Below is Web.Config for Server**

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
 </behavior>
```

Answer (score 7):

Go to the IIS. You find something called "basic settings". Add your permissions and the machine's permissions. It may be you are not allowed to access some boundaries in your network.

- Go to "Start | Settings | Control Panel | Administrative Tools | Local Security Settings".
- Go to Local Policies | Security Options
- Select Network Security : Lan Manager Authentication Level
- Select the 2nd value in the "Drop Down" Send LM & NTLM.........

Also `ClientCredentialType=Windows` makes the authentication header `Negotiate`, which isn't quite enough for it to work with `Negotiate, NTLM`

However, setting `client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowNTLM = True` adds the necessary NTLM to the authentication header, and it works.

Also try running your VS as administrator just in case. :)

Comment: AllowNTLM is deprecated, it says I should set the policy locally? How can I do this?

Comment: Hi there, I have a similar situation. Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to set `ClientCredentialType="Ntlm"`.

Comment: Where do you set this ClientCredentialType in the solution?